# Python : list comprehension + filter

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a string from which I wish to extract vowels and consonants along with their indices.

I am thinking about :

```
a = "HELLO"
list_ = list(a)
vow = [(x, i) for i,x in enumerate(list_) if x in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']]
cons = [(x, i) for i, x in enumerate(list_) if x not in j for j in list_ if j in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']]
```

However, I am getting `NameError` (saying `j` is not defined). Why am I not able to nest my list comprehension.

My desired output :

```
vows : [('E', 1), ('O', 4)]
cons : [('H', 0), ('L', 2), ('L', 3)]
```

Comment: Maybe because you're using two list comprehension at once.

Comment: List comprehensions can be nested, there is something wrong about the way I am doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax would be to explicitely make the inner loop a list comprehension:

```
cons = [(x, i) for i, x in enumerate(list_) if x not in [ j for
            j in list_ if j in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']]]
```

But here the correct way to get consonants would be simply (as already said by others):

```
cons = [(x, i) for i,x in enumerate(list_) if x not in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']]
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue with your second list comprehension is that ideally the `if` condition should go at the end (after the second `for` loop , only then `j` would we accessible). But you really do not need that, simply check if `x` is not in the list of vowels. Example -

```
cons = [(x, i) for i,x in enumerate(list_) if x not in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']]
```

Demo -

```
>>> a = "HELLO"
>>> list_ = list(a)
>>> vow = [(x, i) for i,x in enumerate(list_) if x in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']]
>>> cons = [(x, i) for i,x in enumerate(list_) if x not in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']]
>>> vow
[('E', 1), ('O', 4)]
>>> cons
[('H', 0), ('L', 2), ('L', 3)]
```

---

You can make this a bit faster by using `set` for `vowels` and you do not really need `list_` , you can enumerate over `a` itself, and get exactly same result. Example -

```
vowel_set = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'}
vow = [(x, i) for i,x in enumerate(a) if x in vowel_set]
cons = [(x, i) for i,x in enumerate(a) if x not in vowel_set]
```

Demo -

```
>>> a = "HELLO"
>>> vowel_set = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'}
>>> vow = [(x, i) for i,x in enumerate(a) if x in vowel_set]
>>> cons = [(x, i) for i,x in enumerate(a) if x not in vowel_set]
>>> vow
[('E', 1), ('O', 4)]
>>> cons
[('H', 0), ('L', 2), ('L', 3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You're over-complicating it

```
a = "HELLO"
list_ = list(a)
vow = [(x, i) for i,x in enumerate(list_) if x in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']]
cons = [(x, i) for i, x in enumerate(list_) if x not in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']]
```

See Anand S Kumar's answer for details :)

---

The mistake in your nesting is that you need to nest it again

```
cons = [(x, i) for i, x in enumerate(list_) if x not in [j for j in list_ if j in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Rule #1 about nested LCs in Python: The *outer* loop goes first.

```
cons = [(x, i) for j in list_ if j in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'] for i, x in enumerate(list_) if x not in j]
```

But this will give the wrong result since you should just be using `not in` in the first place instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for membership in a string:

```
>>> 'I' in 'AEIOU'
True
```

You could convert each character in a string to a member of a set, for slightly faster searching:

```
>>> 'Z' in set('AEIOU')
False
```

You don't need the second inner loop:

```
>>> vowels = set('AEIOU')
>>> vows = [(char, index) for index, char in enumerate(word) if char in vowels]
>>> cons = [(char, index) for index, char in enumerate(word) if char not in vowels]
```

Comment: But how can you also get indices this way ?
`if 'L' in 'HELLO':
  print 'HELLO'.find('L')`
This will only give the index of the first occurrence of `L` (here 2)

Comment: My distinction is to check against a string of vowels rather than a list of vowels.